# Update one SQL table while Deleting from another

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two SQL tables (SalesCategory and ProductLine), each with two columns. A product category cannot be associated with a Sales Category and a Product Line at the same time. Users can, however, change, for example, Product Category ABC to be associated with Sales Category 123 instead of Product Line 456. When something like this happens, I want to remove the record of Product Category ABC from the ProductLine SQL table and UPDATE the SalesCategory with the ID of Product Category ABC. But I am not sure how to do this without making another separate DELETE function and calling them inside the save function for the SQL table in question. I feel like I'm putting in too many functions related to these 2 SQL tables....

As an important side note, Product Categories cannot be associated with more than one Product Line or more than one Sales Category.

Is there a better way to setup the code so I don't have a bunch of functions floating around associated with two SQL database tables? Or is this the best way to go about things?

Here is my code as it is now:

```
    //Get current Product Line and Sales Cateogry data for the current Category.
    //These two functions are called in the Page_Load    
    protected string getProductLine()
    {
        string retVal = "";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProductLine FROM ProductLine WHERE uidCategory = @CategoryID", cn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CategoryID", _CategoryId));
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader["ProductLine"].ToString() != "")
                        {
                            productLineTxt.Text = reader["ProductLine"].ToString();
                            retVal = productLineTxt.Text;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            retVal = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    protected string getSalesCategory()
    {
            string retVal = "";
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SalesCat FROM SalesCategory WHERE uidCat = @CategoryID", cn);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CategoryID", _CategoryId));
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (reader["SalesCat"].ToString() != "")
                            {
                                salesCatTxt.Text = reader["SalesCat"].ToString();
                                retVal = salesCatTxt.Text;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                retVal = "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    cn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                //
            }
        return retVal;
    }

    //These two functions are called in the saveSalesCategory() and saveProductLine() functions respectively. They determine if those save functions should perform an UPDATE or INSERT. This is meant to prevent a Product Category from having association with more than one Product Line or Sales Category
    protected bool salesCatExists()
    {
        bool retVal = true;

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Exists' FROM SalesCategory WHERE uidCat = @CategoryID";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CategoryID", _CategoryId));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SalesCategory", salesCatTxt.Text));
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(reader["Exists"]) == 0)
                        {

                            retVal = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            retVal = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            //
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    protected bool productLineExists()
    {
        bool retVal = true;

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Exists' FROM ProductLine WHERE uidCategory = @CategoryID";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CategoryID", _CategoryId));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductLine", productLineTxt.Text));
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(reader["Exists"]) == 0)
                        {

                            retVal = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            retVal = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
           //
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    //Save new or update old Product Line and Sales Category data for the current Category
    protected void saveProductLine()
    {
        try
        {
            string update1 = "UPDATE ProductLine SET ProductLine = @ProductLine WHERE uidCategory = @CategoryID";
            string update2 = "UPDATE ProductLine SET ProductLine = '' AND uidCategory = '' WHERE uidCategory = @CategoryID";
            string insert = "INSERT INTO ProductLine (uidCategory, ProductLine) VALUES(@CategoryID, @ProductLine)";
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CategoryID", _CategoryId));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductLine", productLineTxt.Text));
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                if (getProductLine() == "")
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = insert;
                }
                else
                {
                    productLineTxt.Text = getProductLine();
                    cmd.CommandText = update;
                }
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //
        }
    }

    protected void saveSalesCategory()
    {
        string update = "UPDATE SalesCategory SET SalesCat = @SalesCategory WHERE uidCat = @CategoryID";
        string insert = "INSERT INTO SalesCategory (uidCat, SalesCat) VALUES(@CategoryID, @SalesCategory)";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CategoryID", _CategoryId));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SalesCategory", salesCatTxt.Text));
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                if (salesCatExists() == false)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = insert;
                }
                else
                {

                    cmd.CommandText = update;
                }

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Comment: It might help if you whittled down your code a bit. Perhaps it's just me, but I'm having a bit of trouble trying to figure out what's truly and directly relevant to the question.

Comment: This seems like a good place to use a stored procedure.  Also in `saveProductLine` you are possibly calling `getProductLine()` when once would do.  What functions are you calling now for your case?  Are these new functions you are asking about writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look into the SQL [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement. I'm not sure I completely understand what you're hoping to do enough to give a code example of how it might help you, but that sounds like it might do something like your goal.

It'll let you, for instance, check one table (whether an actual table or just a table-valued-variable) against another given a key or set of keys, then take action when records match or when they don't match.

I suppose I can give a quick example, though:

This query could handle much of the logic in your `saveSalesCategory` method:

```
MERGE SalesCategory AS T
USING (VALUES ((@CategoryID, @SalesCategory)) AS S (uidCat, SalesCat)
ON (T.uidCat = S.uidCat)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET SalesCat = S.SalesCat
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (uidCat, SalesCat) VALUES (S.uidCat, S.SalesCat)
```

As you'll notice, it checks to see whether any records exist, then inserts or updates accordingly. This gets rid of your need to run `salesCatExists()` and use multiple TSQL queries.

I recognize that this doesn't answer your question (I think?) but I hope it at least guides you a bit in the right direction, since I'm still not overly sure what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: This actually did help--it got rid of the salesCatExists() and productLineExists functions, so my code is cleaned up a bit. I had to make a separate function for deletion because it just seemed too complicated to try to do some many things in just one query, be it involving a MERGE or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an update to one table and a delete to another table like this in a single command. It seems that the data structure is what you are fighting the most here. If your ProductCategory table had a column for ReferenceType this would be pretty simple. You would be able to update the ReferenceType and the foreign key value in a single pass. With they way you have put this together you also are going to have challenges with referential integrity because the value in ProductCategory would be a foreign to one or the other table depending on which type it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample looks like it isn't trying to do everything that you descriptions states. Maybe you just hadn't gotten to the delete part. I think a couple of stored procedures might be helpful. I condensed a couple of your methods into one stored proc, and you can do the same thing for the Product Line. I just wasn't sure where to put the DELETE statement. Is this the right direction? If so, we can figure out where to put that delete ;)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SaveSalesCategory
    @CategoryID INT ,
    @SalesCategory INT
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SalesCatCount INT = ( SELECT   COUNT(*) AS 'Exists'
                                       FROM     SalesCategory
                                       WHERE    uidCat = @CategoryID
                                     )

        IF @SalesCatCount = 0 
            BEGIN
                INSERT  INTO SalesCategory
                        ( uidCat, SalesCat )
                VALUES  ( @CategoryID, @SalesCategory )
            END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN
                UPDATE  SalesCategory
                SET     SalesCat = @SalesCategory
                WHERE   uidCat = @CategoryID
            END
    END
GO
```

Comment: I like the use of a sproc here, but depending on how you feel about the `MERGE` syntax, this could be a perfect place to utilize it. I know some people had concerns at least when it was first released, but I've never had any problems with it. The answer I posted shows how to employ it to have the same end-result as the contents of this. I'm not sure one is necessarily better than the other, but it's worth being informed of your options.

Comment: Agreed, the `MERGE` statement doesn't pop into my head immediately, since I don't use it a whole lot, but you're right, it's pretty fitting in this case!

Comment: @MatthewHaugen can merge act on two tables in one statement?

Comment: No, it can't. But you can always utilize the `OUTPUT` clause to do some other actions post-facto based on what the `MERGE` did. For instance, you can do the merge as I described, then `OUTPUT $ACTION` and know whether the record was updated or deleted, then work off of that. That's a basic example, of course. You can also output more columns, save them to a table variable, then work with the entire records. But as far as checking if something exists in one table and doing something in a completely different one, that's more a job for something like @Relevant posted in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use an OUTPUT clause ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx))

```
DELETE ProductLine
WHERE uidCategory = @CategoryID
OUTPUT column1,column2,etc INTO SalesCategory
```

or

```
DELETE SalesCategory
WHERE uidCategory = @CategoryID
OUTPUT column1,column2,etc INTO ProductLine
```

Comment: This is definitely a very clean way of doing what it does, but remember that it won't insert anything if nothing is deleted. So it's definitely a fantastic approach if that's what the OP wants, but she should keep that in mind. This solution is more a matter of moving around existing data, as compared to adding anything new. It might be useful in concert with some other things people have said, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a trigger on both of those tables so that when you insert a new record or update an existing record the DB looks to your other table for that category and deletes that record.

Not all of your parameters were used in your example code and it's kind of long so I don't think this code, as written, will do exactly what you need but the concept I think should work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TRG_SalesCategory_RECORD
   ON  SalesCategory 
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Delete from ProductLine
    Where CategoryID = (select CategoryID from INSERTED)

END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TRG_ProductLine_RECORD
   ON  ProductLine 
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Delete from SalesCategory
    Where CategoryID = (select CategoryID from INSERTED)

END
GO
```